# Wepay-API: This app does not have permission to access this endpoint (account/kyc/authorize/)

Tags: wepay

I am making an online marketplace website using WePay API. I created user merchant accounts using provided client_id, client_secret, access_token, and also created Know Your Customer object using endpoint('account/kyc/create/') it returns me kyc_id but when I make a call to endpoint('account/kyc/authorize/') passing given kyc_id it gives me the following response Response: "This app does not have permission to access this endpoint". Why I am not supposed to access this endpoint. Although I am passing the correct App client_id, client_secret, access_token and making this call on the staging environment.
How to add permission to my app to make this call successful?

Comment: does anyone have no idea about WePay API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default way to collect KYC information for your user is by using WePay's embedded iframe.

From https://www.wepay.com/developer/facilitate_withdrawals/embedded-withdrawals :

> There are two steps for embedding the withdrawal flow in an iframe:
>
> - Make the [`/account/get_update_uri`](https://developer.wepay.com/api-calls/account#update) call
> - Embed the update uri in an iframe on your site
>
> The merchant will be shown a flow where they will verify their identity, add their bank account information...

If you want to complete KYC via APIs, your app must explicitly be given permission to use the `account/kyc/authorize` endpoint. Please contact your account manager at WePay. If you don't have one, you can submit a permission request here: https://support.wepay.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I submitted the permission request.
One more thing I want to know that it is mandatory to register a user and then create their merchant account in that user profile or simply create sub-merchant accounts in application profile???

Comment: @Majid I'm not sure if it is absolutely mandatory, but it is highly recommended that you create new users and merchant accounts for each of your customers.